# How Can I make string expression variable

Tags: vb.net

I made over a hundred checkbox for movie ticketing project(University)
and We have to check what checkbox is checked.
but We couldn't make it through.

I thought

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 180 Step 1
If ("checkbox" & i).checked = True Then
    'blah blah blah
End If
Next
```

I know it's not grammatical-right but you know what I mean.
please help us :( we hold it very long time...

ps. of course, we can make another route to this system.
But I want to know it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all checkboxes in a group box and then make a loop for all checkboxes in it like this:

```
For Each ctrl In GroupBox1.Controls

      If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox)) Then
          Dim chkbx As CheckBox = CType(ctrl, CheckBox)
      End If
    Next
```

Or if you insist on doing it with predefined strings then try something with directcasting:

```
For i as integer = 1 to 180 Step 1
        dim chkbox as Checkbox = DirectCast(Controls("checkbox" & i.ToString), Checkbox )
        If chkbox IsNot Nothing
            ' do something with the object now   
        End If
   Next
```

Comment: And what if in that groupbox is another control per say a panel with checkboxs....? Do you think either of your solutions would work?

Comment: never thought of that, still until reasonable sizes can be hard looped with For Each containertype in form first then for each ctrl in container1-2-3.controls i suppose. or if things get really messy DirectCast or CType or Find from id string would be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I'll check it soon.